PrestaShop 8.1.7: hide feature/attribute on product page
I'm on PrestaShop 8.1.7 and I would hide a feature (not attribute) on product page because I use this features to differentiate discounts based on season (FW22,FW23,FW24...) but I want not shown.
How is possible?
Tanks a lot.
hide features on product page

The quickest way is to create a override of the getFrontFeaturesStatic method in Product class so your features will stay on backoffice but are hidden on front.
For example:
class Product extends ProductCore
{
    public static function getFrontFeaturesStatic($id_lang, $id_product)
    {
        $features = parent::getFrontFeaturesStatic($id_lang, $id_product);
        return array_filter($features, function ($feature) {
            $excluded = [{features to exclude here}];
            return !in_array($feature['value'], $excluded);
        });
    }
}

